# Does SQL Server native client uses any built in driver connection to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database

While reading the document about SQL Server connection, MS explains various data providers in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/data-providers). It says

> The .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server (SqlClient) uses its own protocol to communicate with SQL Server. It is lightweight and performs well because it is optimized to access a SQL Server directly without adding an OLE DB or Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) layer.

Does it mean SQL Server client does not use any driver or it has its own driver?

- K

Comment: The .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server **is** its own driver - it doesn't depend / use OleDB or ODBC or any other technology - it's the **preferred way** of connecting to SQL Server at the lowest level

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient and Microsoft.Data.SqlClient use neither OLEDB nor ODBC. They have their own private driver, SNI. The newer Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, for example, uses interop wrapper classes to invoke functions exported from [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.x64.dll](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netfx/src/Microsoft/Data/Interop/SNINativeManagedWrapperX64.cs) and [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.x86.dll](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netfx/src/Microsoft/Data/Interop/SNINativeManagedWrapperX86.cs).

Comment: Adding that all SQL Server drivers/providers ultimately communicate with SQL Server using the TDS protocol. Both flavors of .NET `SqlClient` managed provider include the assemblies to do that without a separate install and implement ADO.NET interfaces. `System.Data.Client` and it's dependencies are included with the .NET framework. The dependencies for `Microsoft.Data.Client` are included in the corresponding [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/).